# Time Dilation for a photon

Tags: special-relativity, photons, relativity, time-dilation

Does a photon experience any time. Since a photon is massless and hence travels at (c) then it should suffer infinite time dilation, and hence shouldn't experience no time?

Comment: A photon is not an object and it doesn't travel. It's a quantum of a quantum field, which means it's really just a local property. Time dilation doesn't apply to local properties. It applies to clocks, which are macroscopic physical objects/systems.